# Is xd_receiver.htm required?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to diagnose why I am getting a blank popup when I attempt to authenticate to facebook when using IE.

To start, I want to make sure my environment is setup correctly.  I do not have the xd_receiver.htm in the root of my website.

Q: What is the purpose of the xd_receiver.htm and is it needed for use with the facebook-c#-sdk 5.0.3?
Q: If required, does the xd_receiver.htm file need to be only in root or in multiple locations?

Since my app is simple, I am using the following code snip to login.  Once I get logged, I use the facebook-c#-sdk to do some simple POST to me/feed.

```
<fb:login-button ... />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    FB.init({ appId: '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"] %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    function facebook_onlogin_ready() {
    // refresh page
        window.location.reload(true);
    }

</script>
```

Any thoughts on why IE is through a blank popup would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xd_receiver.htm is not required. That was part of the old Javascript SDK. There are a couple of reasons why the popup wouldnt be working in IE. 1) If you are not on port 80 or 443. Facebook's Javascript SDK has a few bugs in IE with non-standard ports. 2) Try setting up your app to run on IIS using a real domain. (You can use local.facebooksdk.net as it points to 127.0.0.1) 3) Make sure your site url match the url you are running your site in exactly. Those config settings are very important.